# combining multiple columns in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

Table A

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
+  ID        +  Name        +   Company ID +
+------------+--------------+--------------+
+   1        +  Steve       +      1       +
+   2        +  Mile        +      2       +
+   3        +  Steve       +      2       +
+   4        +  Del Piero   +      2       +
+   5        +  Jack        +              +
============================+==============+
```

Table B

```
+------------+--------------+
+  ID        +  Company     +
+------------+--------------+
+   1        +  A           +
+   2        +  B           +
============================+
```

What I want

```
+----------+------------+----------------+
+ # of id  +  # OF Name +  # of B Company+
+----------+------------+----------------+
+ 5        +  4         +  3             +
+========================================+
```

I have tried Union//Union All

```
SELECT count(id), count(name) FROM table A
UNION 
SELECT count(company) FROM table B where company = 'B'
```

I should keep these columns but Union doesn't allow a different number of columns.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT count(id),
count(name),
(SELECT count(company) FROM table B where company)
FROM table A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables to recover the company name associated to each record in `tablea`, then aggregate:

```
select
    count(*) no_ids,
    count(distinct a.name) no_names,
    sum(b.comany = 'B') no_b_company
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on b.id = a.company_id
```

Presumably, `id` is the primary key of `tablea`, so we just use `count(*)` to summarize this column. `no_names` counts how many different names can be seen in the corresponding column, and `sum(b.company = 'B')` increase by `1` everytime  company B is seen.

If there is a possibility of missing companies in `tableb`, you can change the `inner join` to a `left join`.

Comment: @hellomynameis: ok, so you want a `left join` - see the end of my answer..